# Connecting to external URL from WatchKit 2.0

Tags: apple-watch, nsurlrequest, watchconnectivity

I would like to load some information in the `WatchKit` interface from a `REST` backoffice. Is there some fast way to execute a URL request passing by the host `iOS` app or I must concoct a specific protocol taking advantage of the bare `WatchConnectivity` functionalities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using sendMessageData:replyHandler:, yet I have problems in having it properly working. The relative ticket is at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211760/sendmessagedata-does-not-call-didreceivemessagedata-on-the-counterpart

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSURLSession directly from your WatchKit extension.

Comment: That is quite weird as the Watch lacks a sim card and so it is not able to connect to the internet by itself, but perhaps under Wifi coverage. I am looking for a way to submit an URL both under wifi and cellular coverage. I was considering using WCSession.sendMessage with an handler on which the main app would put the result after having performed an URLS request itself. Yet I am not clear whether that also works hen the main app is not active.

Comment: NSURLSession will take advantage of the phone's cellular if needed and available

Answer (score 0):

NSURLSession works fine with Watchkit, but you will need to add Allows Arbitrary Loads on Watchkit Extension too if it is relevant.

Please see this post,

[NSURLSession returns data as Null on Watch OS2 using Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098581/nsurlsession-returns-data-as-null-on-watch-os2-using-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Although Apple's example is in swift see https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-228/?time=345 , I've pasted a snippet in obejctive-c  utlisin the NSProcessInfo wrapper.

Apple's example also makes use of Semaphore's, should the extension be put to sleep, which I have omitted from below.

Following the below pattern enables you to hit a desired service directly from the watch.

```
NSProcessInfo *processInfo = [NSProcessInfo processInfo];

[processInfo performExpiringActivityWithReason:@"networkReq" usingBlock:^(BOOL expired) {
    if (!expired){            
        NSLog(@"we have an assertion");        
        NSTimeInterval secondsInThreeHours = 3 * 60 * 60;
        NSURL *forecast = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http::address"];

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        [[session dataTaskWithURL:forecast
                completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                    NSURLResponse *response,
                                    NSError *error) {
                    // handle response
         }] resume];
    else{

        NSLog(@"Not background assertion or we are out of time");
    }
}];
```